# jQuery accordion - put cursor focus on search text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

- Figured out, thanks!

I am trying to set focus on the search textbox when the 'Search' accordion is clicked.

Here is my js code:

```
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    event: "click hoverintent",
    autoHeight: false,
    activate: function (event, ui) {
    $("#searchForm input:text").first().focus();
   }
});

$("#Search_Term").autocomplete(
    {
        source: arrEmp,
        minLength: 2,
        delay: 100

    });
```

And here is HTML:

```
 <body>
   <div id="accordion">

  <h3>Section 1</h3>

    <div>
       Loreum ipsum tes

    </div>

 <h3>Section 2</h3>

    <div>

        <form id="searchForm">
            Search
            <input type="text" name="Search_Term" id="Search_Term" />
            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" />
        </form>

    </div>

  <h3>Section 3</h3>

    <div>
        <p>Data Test</p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works if I copy/paste these code in JS Fiddle, but for some reason, it doesn't work in my code.

Comment: Are you placing the code inside a [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler?

Comment: yes, its in nthe document.ready functio

Answer (score 0):

try this first with its id like this

```
$("#Search_Term").focus();
```

if you want to call like you mentioned try this

```
$("#searchForm input[type='text']:first").focus();
```

please make sure you are writing this is $(document).ready()

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try this :

`$('#accordion').click(function()
{
$(this).find('h3').next('div').find("input#Search_Term").focus();
});`

Comment: not sure if I can do this, I also need to use click hoverintent as you can see in my code